# Transform an integer value to a repeated character

Tags: xml, xslt

When my XSL stylesheets encounters this node:

```
<node attribute="3"/>
```

...it should transform it into this node:

```
<node attribute="***"/>
```

My template matches the attribute and recreates it, but I don't know how to set the value to: the character '*' repeated as many times as the value of the original attribute.

```
<xsl:template match="node/@attribute">
    <xsl:variable name="repeat" select="."/>
    <xsl:attribute name="attribute">
        <!-- What goes here? I think I can do something with $repeat... -->
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: Suppose that we can do this... why? Isn't `3` much easier to work at the data layer? `***` seems to only make sense in the presentation layer.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for an XSLT 2.0 solution.

Comment: @polygenelubricants: I concur if this is a data-to-data transform, but XSLT can be used for the data-to-presentation transform as well. At this point, the question would be valid.

Comment: @polygenelubricants It's for the presentation layer, Adobe InDesign to be more precise. I can use the characters in combination with a font to print special glyphs (think about a 3-star hotel that you would find in a brochure).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A fairly dirty but pragmatic approach would be to make a call on what's the highest number you ever expect to see in `attribute`, then use

```
substring("****...", 1, $repeat)
```

where you have as many `*`s in that string as that maximum number you expect. But I hope that there's something better!

Comment: +1 this is the fastest approach if you know the maximum no. of repetitions beforehand.

Answer (score 9):

Generic, recursive solution (XSLT 1.0):

```
<xsl:template name="RepeatString">
  <xsl:param name="string" select="''" />
  <xsl:param name="times"  select="1" />

  <xsl:if test="number($times) &gt; 0">
    <xsl:value-of select="$string" />
    <xsl:call-template name="RepeatString">
      <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$string" />
      <xsl:with-param name="times"  select="$times - 1" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Call as:

```
<xsl:attribute name="attribute">
  <xsl:call-template name="RepeatString">
    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="'*'" />
    <xsl:with-param name="times"  select="." />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:attribute>
```

Answer (score 7):

Adding to the two nice answers of @AakashM and @Tomalak, **this is done naturally in XSLT 2.0**:

**This XSLT 2.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@attribute">
   <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
     <xsl:for-each select="1 to .">
       <xsl:value-of select="'*'"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<node attribute="3"/>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
<node attribute="***"/>
```

**Do note** how the XPath 2.0 `to` operator is used in the `<xsl:for-each>` instruction.

Comment: I will have to try if the software (InDesign CS3) supports XSLT 2.0, but good answer, thanks!