# XSLT produce nice indentation when generating text

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to create a XSLT-Transformation, which transforms a xml document to a text format. This text format is structured and thus should be formatted accordingly, namely indented.

For example:

Given this document,

```
<root>
    <l1>
        <l2>
            <l3>
                <l4>
                </l4>
            </l3>
            <l3>
                <l4>
                </l4>
            </l3>
        </l2>
    </l1>
</root>
```

I want this as output:

```
l1 (
    l3 (
        foo (
            l4 (
            )
        )
    )
    l3 (
        foo (
            l4 (
            )
        )
    )
)
```

If there were more levels, they should be indented even deeper. The exact depth of the xml document is variable. Additionaly, it should be possible to remove or add certain nodes, as can be seen in the example with nodes "foo" and "l2".

Is this possible in a maintainable way using xslt? Version is xslt-1.0 with exslt.

Regards,
Jost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Something like the following**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vSpaces" select=
 "'                                                                 '"/>

 <xsl:template match="*/*">
  <xsl:param name="pIndent" select="0"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="substring($vSpaces, 1, $pIndent)"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), ' (')"/>
     <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
       <xsl:with-param name="pIndent" select="$pIndent+string-length(name())+3"/>
     </xsl:apply-templates>
     <xsl:value-of select=
     "substring($vSpaces, 1, $pIndent+ string-length(name()))"/>
     <xsl:text>)&#xA;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
    <l1>
        <l2>
            <l3>
                <l4>
                </l4>
            </l3>
            <l3>
                <l4>
                </l4>
            </l3>
        </l2>
    </l1>
</root>
```

**the correctly-indented output is produced**:

```
l1 (
     l2 (
          l3 (
               l4 (
                 )
            )
          l3 (
               l4 (
                 )
            )
       )
  )
```

> Additionaly, it should be possible to remove or add certain nodes, as
>   can be seen in the example with nodes "foo" and "l2".

**Organize your transformation in two passes**, where in the first pass you transform the source XML document into the wanted final XML document. Then in the second pass apply the above transformation to produce the wanted text result.

For more information search for "XSLT multi-pass transformation".

Comment: I'll take your approach, especially the two-pass-thing. But instead of selecting a substring of some long string, I will use a function to create the tabs for indentation. How that works can be found here, second answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228270/transform-an-integer-value-to-a-repeated-character

Comment: @Jost, If you use primitive recursion for filling  the desired string, you could crash with stack overflow exception for N ~ 1000. There is another resursive solution that works smoothly for filling even millions of characters. If you are interested to know more about this technique, please, feel free to ask a question.

Comment: Actually, N around 1000 should be enough for my application. But this other way does still interest me, so could you please elaborate or give me some search words or something?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all you need to do is to prepend a number of tabs/spaces to your output for each LEVEL of iteration.