# XSLT - Print Child node names (Tree Structure / Folder Explorer Style)

Tags: xml, xslt

Need expert help to get desired output using XSLT. Basically trying to find a way to do the tree structure or folder navigation. If the root node has child node, I would need to set `type : object`. and out put the child node names under `properties:`. The xml is dynamic and I will not know the node names since it comes from database.

**XML**

```
<response>
    <Node_A_1>
        <Node_B_1>P</Node_B_1>
        <Node_B_2>
            <Node_C_1>B</Node_C_1>
            <Node_C_2>B</Node_C_2>
        </Node_B_2>
        <Node_B_3>4110838</Node_B_3>            
    </Node_A_1>
    <Node_A_2>
        <Node_B_6>Ok</Node_B_6>
        <Node_B_7>
            <Node_C_6>2016-04-13T08:57:23.552-05:00</Node_C_6> 
        </Node_B_7>
        <Node_B_8>200</Node_B_8>
    </Node_A_2>
```

**Expected Out Put**

```
response:
    type: Object
    properties: 
      Node_A_1:
         type: Object
         properties: 
           Node_B_1:
             type: string 
           Node_B_2:
             type: Object
             properties:
                Node_C_1:
                   type: string
                Node_C_2:
                   type: string
           Node_B_3:
              type: string
      Node_A_2:
         type: object
         properties:
            Node_B_6
               type: String
            Node_B_7
               type: object  
               properties:
                  Node_C_6
                     type: String
            Node_B_8
                type: String
```

So far I have come up with the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" />
    <xsl:template match="*" name="makeUL">
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="name()" /> 
            <xsl:call-template name="makeUL"/> 
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Current OUTPUT**

```
response

    Node_A_1
        Node_B_1
        Node_B_2
            Node_C_1
            Node_C_2
        Node_B_3
    Node_A_2
        Node_B_6
        Node_B_7
            Node_C_6
        Node_B_8
```

Now I need to find a way to check if the node has child node, so that I can print `type:object` and print `type:string` if the nodes doesn't have any child nodes. These attributes (type, properties) are not part of XML but will be derived basing on the existence of child nodes.

Comment: To improve your question, please read this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Object types don't seem to be included in the source XML.  Do you make them up on the fly? Based on what?  Why is `Node_C_6` a string and not a "date"? Your requirements are incomplete.  Also, you are expected to make an effort yourself first and show your work. What have you written so far?

Comment: Hi Jim, as per your instructions, I have added the information what I had so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[*]">
    <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        <br/>
        <xsl:text>type: object</xsl:text>
        <br/>
        <xsl:text>properties:</xsl:text>
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ul>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        <br/>
        <xsl:text>type: string </xsl:text>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Edit:

> Sorry for the confusion. This is not for the Browser UI purpose. I am
>   trying to send the txt response

For a text output, try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*[*]">
    <xsl:param name="indent"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$indent"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#10;', $indent)"/>
    <xsl:text>    type: object</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#10;', $indent)"/>
    <xsl:text>    properties:</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:with-param name="indent" select="concat($indent, '      ')"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:param name="indent"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$indent"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#10;', $indent)"/>
    <xsl:text>   type: string </xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Great. Thank you for help.  how could I achieve indentation, without ul/li.  tried to use recursive solution (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3228339/6201539). but I bet I was doing something wrong.

Comment: "*how could I achieve indentation*" In what medium? I used ul/li because your question tried to use ul/li - which suggests HTML as the target. If you do intend to display this in a browser, then ul/li probably is the best choice.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. This is not for the Browser UI purpose. I am trying to send the txt response from a Restful Web Service.

Answer (score 0):

The basic solution is like already from michael.hor257k to have a template for elements with child elements:

```
<xsl:template match="*[*]">
```

and one for this without child elements :

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
```

The predicate (`[not(*)]`)  is not really  because the match `*[*]` has hire priority.

Try:

```
    <xsl:template match="*[*]">
        <li>
            <span><xsl:value-of select="name()" /></span>
            <ul>
                <li>type: Object</li>
                <li>
                    <span>
                        <xsl:text>properties:</xsl:text>
                    </span>
                    <ul>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
        <li>
            <span><xsl:value-of select="name()" /></span>
            <ul>
                <li>type: string</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
     </xsl:template>
```

Which will generate:

response

- type: Object
- properties:

  - Node_A_1

    - type: Object
    - properties:

      - Node_B_1

        - type: string
      - Node_B_2

        - type: Object
        - properties:

          - Node_C_1

            - type: string
          - Node_C_2

            - type: string
      - Node_B_3

        - type: string
  - Node_A_2

    - type: Object
    - properties:

      - Node_B_6

        - type: string
      - Node_B_7

        - type: Object
        - properties:

          - Node_C_6

            - type: string
      - Node_B_8

        - type: string